# How to generate the language of all binary strings of length n-1 using a DCG in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
z(1) --> [].
z(N) --> [0] , z(Nm), {N is Nm+1}.
z(N) --> [1] , z(Nm), {N is Nm+1}.
```

This is what I have so far. I want to generate

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[1,0]
[1,1]
```

but instead runs into an infinite loop after [0, 0]

when you query

```
?- z(3, X, []).
```

Comment: Why did you remove your question? This way no one will even understand the answer. Please consider that the answer is not just for yourself but could also help others. You should be able to comment your own question, where you can say "thank you".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will always call the predicate with N as integer, you can try:

```
z(1) --> [].
z(N) --> [0] , {N>1, Nm is N-1}, z(Nm).
z(N) --> [1] , {N>1, Nm is N-1}, z(Nm).
```

Result:

```
?- z(3, X, []).
X = [0, 0] ;
X = [0, 1] ;
X = [1, 0] ;
X = [1, 1] ;
false.
```

Comment: Why the test `integer(N)`? By that `phrase(z(N), L)` produces a single solution and then (quietly and incorrectly) fails.

Comment: @false That test has been eliminated, thanks!